# What does BizSpark currently offer?

Tags: bizspark

I am looking at bizspark but the page with the software seems outdated. I am wondering if anyone has a current list or can confirm if that is the current list.

http://www.bizspark.com/v2/Programs/Pages/BizSpark_Software_and_Tools.aspx

Like it still say you get Vs 2008? How about 2010? What version of 2010? How many licenses?

Comment: contact your local MS representative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have BizSpark, and VS2010 Ultimate is available for download, just like Office 2010 (although there are limitations on the way you're allowed to use Office).

In a nutshell, BizSpark gives you free [MSDN Premium](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx) subscriptions - only without support. The [BizSpark FAQ](http://www.bizspark.com/v2/Programs/Pages/BizSpark_FAQ.aspx) also has some helpful information.

Comment: Microsoft Office is included, so it's worth it even if you're not a Microsoft shop. Are there any conditions on getting accepted to it?

Comment: @mneemosyn - too bad. Cool nick btw ... it reminds me of a character from the Hyperion series.